# Azure Application Gateways and response compression?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We're using an Application Gateway at the moment for our application.  It serves two purposes: provide an HTTPS endpoint for public access to our app, and using a Path Rule to redirect incoming requests to the appropriate backend pool based on the URL of the request.  Working fine so far.

We're looking at using compression for our responses to reduce the payload being delivered back to the client.  Is is possible to enable compression at the Application Gateway?  So, when it receives a response, it could compress it before returning it back to the caller?  We're trying to determine if we implement this in our application itself (sitting in the backend pools) or can we do this in the App Gateway.

If not, would there be any plans for this?

Comment: I have the same question and im concerned it will decompress between the server and gateway and then encrypt without compression to the client.

Comment: FYI, I haven't found anything regarding this.  At the moment, my server behind the app gateway is compressing the response, and the gateway is certainly sending it back through compressed and encrypted.

Comment: You can vote for this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/20368618-application-gateway-waf-support-gzipped-content-i

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing in my AG responses this header without making any special config:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

So I think it is compressing. I don't know how long this has been working though.